# Uploading excel files in RShiny

Tags: r, excel, user-interface, server, shiny

I am trying to upload excel file with multiple sheets in R using shiny library. Also, I have to upload multiple excel files.
Can anyone tell how to solve this

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @RemkoDuursma I tried using read_excel but sheet wise i couldn't load

Comment: Are you talking about uploading onto a shiny server?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple Shiny utility to open Excel workbooks and load an individual worksheet from a drop down list.  It then displays the table.  Hopefully, this can get you started.

```
# Utility to read any Excel workbook and display a worksheet

library("shiny")
library("gdata")
library("tableHTML")

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Utility to read and display an Excel spreadsheet"),
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel (label="Data Source",
                  # Spreadsheet name and sheet name 
                  fileInput("spreadsheetName", "Spreadsheet Name",accept = c(".xlsx")),
                  selectInput(inputId = "worksheet", label="Worksheet Name",choices=''),
                  actionButton(inputId = "getData",label="Get Data")),

    mainPanel (
     tableHTML_output("table1Data")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Read the data from the spreadsheet
  observe({
    # Get the annual data
    # Check if file is there... if not, exit and wait for it again
    inFile <- input$spreadsheetName
    if (is.null(inFile)) {
      return (NULL)
    }
    else {
      # Set up the selection for the worksheet names within the selected file
      filePath <<- inFile$datapath
      selectionWorksheet <- sort(unique(sheetNames (inFile$datapath)))
      updateSelectInput(session, "worksheet", choices = selectionWorksheet)
    }
  })

  # Get data
  observeEvent(input$getData, {

    # Get the data from the spreadsheet worksheets
    worksheetData <- read.xls (filePath, sheet=input$worksheet, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    # Print the Annual table
    output$table1Data <- renderTable ({
      worksheetData
    # End of main program
    })
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```